Error: An Ionic Router is required for IonRouterContext
I am using Ionic Framework, and Firebase in a React and Typescript project and coming across the error 'An Ionic Router is required for IonRouterContext' when trying to navigate after successful auth login.
I have tried removing the AppRoutes file and having it all in App.tsx but still experiencing the error.
App.tsx
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonApp>
            <IonReactRouter>
                <IonRouterOutlet>
                    <AppRoutes />
                </IonRouterOutlet>
            </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
    )
}

export default App


appRoutes.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react'

import Dashboard from '@/pages/dashboard'

import SignUp from '@/components/onboarding/signup'
import Login from '@/components/onboarding/login'
import Landing from '@/components/onboarding/landing'

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/onboarding" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
    )
}

export default AppRoutes


landing.tsx (the routes here to go to the login and signup components work)
import React from 'react'
import { IonContent, IonButton, IonPage, IonNavLink } from '@ionic/react'

import '@/styles/onboarding/landing.scss'
import SignUp from './signup'
import Login from './login'

const Landing: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="buttons ion-float-bottom">
                        <IonNavLink routerDirection="forward" component={() => <SignUp />}>
                            <IonButton className="signup-btn" fill="solid" expand="block">
                                Create an account
                            </IonButton>
                        </IonNavLink>
                        <IonNavLink routerDirection="forward" component={() => <Login />}>
                            <IonButton className="login-btn" fill="outline" expand="block">
                                Sign In
                            </IonButton>
                        </IonNavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </>
    )
}

export default Landing


login.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { IonPage, IonContent, IonHeader, IonInput, IonButton, IonItem, IonButtons, IonBackButton, useIonRouter } from '@ionic/react'
import { loginUser } from '@/auth/firebase'

import '@/styles/onboarding/login.scss'

const Login: React.FC = () => {
    const router = useIonRouter()

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null)

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const user = await loginUser(email, password)

            if (user) {
                // Login successful, redirect to dashboard
                router.push('/dashboard')
            } else {
                setError('Invalid email or password')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`---error:`, error)

            setError('Error logging in')
        }
    }

    return (
        <IonPage className="login-page">
            <IonHeader>
                <IonButtons slot="start">
                    <IonBackButton defaultHref="/" />
                </IonButtons>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent className="ion-padding">
                <IonItem>
                    <IonInput type="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} onIonChange={e => setEmail(e.detail.value!)} />
                </IonItem>
                <IonItem>
                    <IonInput type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onIonChange={e => setPassword(e.detail.value!)} />
                </IonItem>

                {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}

                <IonButton id="login-button" expand="block" onClick={handleLogin}>
                    Login
                </IonButton>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    )
}

export default Login


router.push('/dashboard') is the problem here and is giving me that error. Is my structure incorrect?

why do you have two ionRouterOutlet?  I guess ionReactRouter should be inside children of ionRouterOutlet
